# Copying Data from an AWS RDS instance to another RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I would like to copy all the data (all the databases and tables) from a RDS instance to another. Can somebody tell me how can this be done. New to AWS so pardon me if my question is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to clone your instance, you don't need to copy all data, you can just create a snapshot and create a new instance from this snapshot.

Now if you really want to copy all data, because the target instance already exists or any other reason, you can use AWS DMS to do this for you.

**Reference**
Creating a DB Snapshot
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html

Tutorial: Restore a DB Instance from a DB Snapshot
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.RestoringFromSnapshot.html

AWS Database Migration Service Step-by-Step Walkthroughs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/DMS-SBS-Welcome.html